# How to connect to an on-premise SQL Server from Azure Powershell runbook?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, powershell, automation

I want to export SQL Server 2016 query output into Azure blob storage account. Part of this I need to establish connection between our company SQL Server 2016 in an Azure Powershell runbook.

Could anyone suggest on how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Upendar

Comment: Looks like you need a gateway connection to reach your server on-prem. Take a look on this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#:~:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%2C%20create,the%20gateway%20resource%20you%20want.
From there you can install SqlServer module for PS

Comment: Hi @Upendar Avireni, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

@UncleCisco provided example [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%2C%20create,the%20gateway%20resource%20you%20want) to connect to the on-premise SQL Server database. We need the gateway to build the connection.

Others also have asked the same question, the answer give us a blog which teachs us how to establish connection between our company SQL Server 2016 in an Azure Powershell runbook.

Ref here:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/405822/how-to-connect-to-an-on-premise-sql-server-from-az.html
2. [Azure Automation Runbook to interact with On-Prem SQL via Hybrid
   Runbook Worker](https://model-technology.com/blog/azure-automation-runbook-to-interact-with-on-prem-sql-via-hybrid-runbook-worker/):

HTH.